# how to toggle vs code's little outline with a shortcut rather than a click on the current variable/function?

Tags: visual-studio-code

## I want to toggle this little menu with a shortcut because it's easier to navigate with it with collapse and fold abstractions

##### I already know and not looking to:

- using the workbench's outline.
- using Go To in the command palette

**I want to toggle this menu specifically with a shortcut or a way to setup the shortcut**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is "Focus and Select Breadcrumbs", by default bound to <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+.</kbd>